# Understanding the rigorous definition of hold time

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, vlsi

Consider the attached from Weste and Harris's (WH) *CMOS VLSI Design*. I follow all of the discussion and definitions except for the hold time definition.

[image]

Now I am familiar with the common/heuristic hold time definition which says something like "the time relative to the clock edge (measured positive past the clock edge) during which the data input must be stable for correct operation". There are of course analogous heuristic definitions for \$t_{setup}\$ and I do understand how these connect to the underlying definition given by WH. However, I can't follow for \$t_{hold}\$. Indeed, I don't even understand what they mean by "clock to D" here.

**Edit:**

In this edit I include the next page which may shed some light on my question.

[image]

My understanding/guess about the hold time is now the following. Let's focus on the given flip-flop intending to capture a \$D = 0\$ input. We examine first the "D falls Q falls" curve. We define \$t_{setup}\$ as the \$t_{DC}\$ at which the slope of the \$t_{CQ}(t_{DC})\$ curve equals -1. The corresponding \$t_{CQ}\$ value is called \$t_{pcq}\$ (the reason this definition makes sense is that, in our design, we will always arrange things such that tokens arrive before \$t_{setup}\$ so that, per the Figure, \$t_{pcq}\$ will indeed be an upper bound on \$t_{CQ}\$). We can also define \$t_{ccq}\$ as \$t_{CQ}\$ in the \$t_{DC} \to \infty \$ limit.

**Now for hold time:** We begin by examining the "D rises Q falls" curve. First of all, we notice that it has a vertical asymptote. We take this as implying that if D rises any earlier than this vertical asymptote then the flip-flop captures a 1 (rather than a 0) incorrectly. (An analogous comment applies to the vertical asymptote for "D falls Q falls".) Now among all of these times at which D can change to 1 and yet the flip-flop still correctly captures a 0, we see that the earlier this change happens the longer it takes for the flip-flop to capture that 0 (this presumably has to do with the inverters in the feedback loops of the flip-flop fighting each other, but we'll leave that aside). Among these \$t_{DC}\$, the hold time is defined as the negative of the maximum \$t_{DC}\$ such that \$t_{CQ} \leq t_{pcq}\$. This matches the definition given on the previous page by WH: "The hold time is the minimum delay from clock to D changing [i.e. \$-t_{DC}\$] such that the \$t_{CQ} \leq t_{pcq}\$ [and such that we get correct capture of the token].

My questions are as follows:

(1) Do you agree with my understanding of the hold time definition?

(2) Why is the added requirement of "such that the \$t_{CQ} \leq t_{pcq}\$" in the hold time definition necessary? Why not define the hold time as the vertical asymptote alluded to above? I think the answer is that our timing parameter definitions are such that, if we meet them, then we are guaranteed a maximum \$t_{CQ}\$ of \$t_{pcq}\$ whereas if we relaxed the hold time definition to be at that vertical asymptote then we might have huge \$t_{CQ}\$ delays. I would appreciate confirmation on this point.

(3) WH write "If D is a very short pulse. the flip-flop may fail to capture it even if D is stable during the setup and hold times around the rising clock edge." How can this be? Wasn't setup and hold time defined (among other things) to give a window during which we would get correct token capture if the D input is stable?

**Edit 2:**
As noted in a comment below, this version of the text has an error (a crucial one!) which is explained in an erratum by the authors below:
[image]

Comment: I expect "clock to D" is the hold time. They seem to have chosen an awkward way of stating things generally.

Comment: it's not `clock to D` ... it is `clock to changing` of D

Comment: Are you saying that \$t_{hold}\$ is defined as the minimum \$t_{DC}\$ (this is D to clock per the above) which is such that the corresponding \$t_{CQ}\$ (which is a function of \$t_{DC}\$ is less than or equal to \$t_{pcq}\$. Per the Figure 10.35, wouldn't this definition lead to \$t_{hold} = -t_{setup}\$ (the minus sign coming from the definition of the positive direction for hold time) since for any \$t_{DC} < t_{setup}\$ we have \$t_{CQ} > t_{pcq}\$ (basically the \$t_{CQ}(t_{DQ})\$ function is monotonic)? @Andyaka

Comment: @jsotola I agree, but (calling this \$t_{CD}\$ since they don't give notation to it) wouldn't we arrive at the conclusion I wrote to Andy above? I must be missing something.

Comment: @EE18 I believe it means the length of time D has to remain stable after clock has occurred.

Comment: I agree heuristically, but as you can see they give a definition which is a little bit more elaborate than that. It seems to be "the length of time D has to remain stable after the clock such that, even if the flip flop captures the token, the \$t_{CQ}\$ is greater than \$t_{pcq}\$". @Andyaka

Comment: @jsotola I have written a lengthy edit and would appreciate hearing what you think. Thank you!

Comment: @Andyaka As above, I'd also appreciate hearing what you think about this edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of what's being discussed is to determine practical values of setup and hold time while being able to treat the flip-flop circuit as a black box. This method is reasonable, and produces a model that will work over a lot more conditions while not being overly conservative. What is described here is an algorithm/method.

Consider Fig. 10:36, annotated for just the D falling case. First, consider that this is not a single simulation occurring - in the "D falls, Q rises case", the value stored in the flop is '0', while the "D falls, Q falls" case starts with a '1'.

Understanding what's going on in the red and yellow parts of this curve, part of the 'D' signal change has made it into the latches and the internal value has begun to change. In the red region, you have low confidence that you will be able to predict the value stored in the flop, or eventually you will know you have the *wrong* value. This is the metastability mentioned in the second page. Further away from that point, you may have confidence that you know the value, but the CLK->Q timing will be negatively impacted. In a timing library where you give only one value for CLK->Q regardless of the D->CLK timing, that introduces an extra uncounted delay that may result in timing failures in fabricated parts. Finally, you can increase your setup and hold margins so much that you have no measurable benefits - you are sandbagging more than needed.

[image]

Going back to your questions:

1. Yes, I believe you have correctly stated what "hold" means. I agree that you understand the WH method for selecting an optimal hold time.
2. Your understanding is correct. Relaxing the setup or hold time (reducing the aperture using the WH terminology) will result in increased CLK->Q delay that is not properly considered.
3. If you take a rule-like interpretation to setup and hold, then you would expect that if you satisfy both setup and hold, you will store the expected state with the expected CLK->Q delay. This is a reasonable interpretation, but you might run into the case where barely meeting both setup and hold will result in the incorrect value being latched. In this case, our model/abstraction of the flip-flop may not be accurate enough for all the use cases. Usually, you have either long logic paths that push against your setup constraint but easily meet hold time, OR extremely short paths (or clock skew) that push against your hold constraint but easily meet setup. Having a timing arc where both occur is uncommon, which leads to the implicit  assumption here, which is that setup and hold is valid if D is only changing *once*. Reality can be a bit more complicated. If you need your setup and hold to guarantee short pulses on D, then you should either find a way of ensuring that a minimum width is enforced, or de-rate setup/hold to ensure that a signal barely meeting setup *and* hold is properly captured.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, thank you so much! In particular your answer to my Q2 via " In a timing library where you give only one value for CLK->Q regardless of the D->CLK timing, that introduces an extra uncounted delay that may result in timing failures in fabricated parts" is extremely helpful. An aside: I am realizing that the screenshots I've taken are from an old version of the textbook and this particular part has an erratum which is actually crucial! My print copy is updated and does not have this error.  I have included a screenshot explaining the erratum and I mention this...

Comment: ...only because you may want to update your very useful figure for others in the future with the new Figure 10.36 (e.g. in my case of trying to capture a 0 on the D input, it's the "D falls Q falls" and "D rises Q falls" which are the relevant curves, not "D falls Q falls" and "D falls Q rises" as you currently have).

Comment: Lastly, I have accepted your answer but was hoping to follow up as I don't fully understand what you are saying with respect to Q3. Are you saying that the quoted line from WH is saying that *if* D is stable throughout the aperture window then it is guaranteed to be captured correctly, but *if* D is only stable around the setup and hold times around the clock edge then the flop is not necessarily going to capture the token (because there is the possibility that D pulses the *other* way at some other points during the aperture window)? I ask only because this seems like an absurd edge case, no?

Comment: @EE18 I updated the discussion on Q3, hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: I am still not sure I totally follow (was my comment above at all on the right track?) but perhaps in due course I will come back to this and understand. Thank you again for all of your help here!

Comment: No, I don't think so. Suppose I wanted to latch a '1' on a flip-flop. The input was a '0' for a long time, and switches to a '1' *just* in time to meet the setup requirement for the related clock pulse. Immediately after the specified hold time, the input goes from a '1' back to a '0', barely satisfying the hold time requirement. In theory, since I met both setup and hold, the flip-flop should be storing a '1'. However, the pulse is *very* short, and might not be stored properly, impacting CLK->Q or even storing the wrong value.

Comment: Since we typically measure setup and hold with a *single* transition of D per clock cycle, we don't actually measure the minimum pulse width required to latch the value of D while meeting setup and hold. Again, this is a *very* short pulse, if you look at the timing charts the aperture window is around an inverter delay or less.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the nature of these graphs then. Are you saying that these graphs assume one transition on D per clock cycle? You write "In theory, since I met both setup and hold, the flip-flop should be storing a '1'. However, the pulse is very short, and might not be stored properly, impacting CLK->Q or even storing the wrong value." Indeed, I thought meeting both setup and hold meant we're guaranteed to capture the right token. But I guess you are saying that these graphs give us guarantees when we "challenge" one or the other of hold or setup. That is, for example, the...

Comment: ..."D Rises Q Rises" graph tells us that if we get our data rising to a '1' before a setup time then we will capture the '1' on Q *assuming this is the only change anywhere near the clock edge*. Separately, the "D Falls Q Rises" graph tells us that if we have D = '1' for a while (importantly, for a while!) and then have D fall to 0 outside of a hold time then we will still capture Q = '1'. But these graphs tell us nothing *necessarily* if we have D rising just before a setup and then falling just after a hold. Is that a correct understanding of your answer to Q3?

Comment: You are correct. These graphs are made with a single D transition per clock, and so WH is disclosing a potential issue when "blindly" trusting your setup and hold analysis. While I don't have exhaustive experience running a static timing analysis tool, I'm struggling to come up with a use case where this is a practical limitation.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much again for your help and patience with me on this one W5VO!